# Is session used to REST authentication?

Tags: session, authentication, rest

Sorry for the noobish question, this is the first time i try to implement a REST interface (in PHP). Anyway, because the stateless nature of HTTP protocol, what's the best practice in order to ensure that:

```
GET/ /user/{id}/friends
```

is always and only executed by the current authenticated user? Is session usually used as a method to restrict REST access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTTP sessions, which are nothing more than server-side cookies. They're usually ok, but there has been a lot of reports of session hijacking lately. So my answer if you're really concerned about this is to use [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). It's tricky to set up, but once it is you can be sure that the message really did come from an authenticated user.

Comment: I'm really concerned about REST philosophy... is session ok REST POV?