# Rest Approach: for Implementing subsequent api calls after Login

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication, hmac

I am trying to implement the Rest approach for designing my Api.

Please go through the work flow below and try to clear my doubts and also point out mistakes-

1. Client(Web browser)
   Rest call from client ->/post /login username/password
2. Server
   /login service checks with the DB if the username & password are correct
   Responds ok:200 + sends back data-> X
3. Client
   receives confirmation that user is authenticated + data -> X
   Now uses data X for subsequent calls to the server to get User specific info through other service calls

/get/FirstName_of_User/X
or

/get/LastName_of_User/X

**now my doubts are the following(what are the best practices for doing the following)**

1. Since for subsequent requests we need to tell the service whose data are we requesting what should the X be ? (Username or temporary token created(does not makes sense since Rest is all about being stateless) or something else ? )
2. Once this X is returned where should it be stored on the client side so that it can be sued  for every subsequent requests ? (Cookie or some other way exists) ?
3. if this is how i make the subsequent calls
    
   **/get/FirstName_of_User/X**

if this call is made by someone else too then it would give the result, i want the person just logged in to get the result only..

Reg doubt 3 - i found this link on stackoverflow -  [Is session used to REST authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439553/is-session-used-to-rest-authentication)

which suggests using HMAC and found this link - http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/ which talks about how HMAC can be used for Rest(basically talks about having a private key on both the client and the server and using it to hash the request)..

My doubt regarding this approach is - say i use password as the private key which both the client and server know about.. then on the client side should we just save the password in the cookies fr hashing each subsequent requests ??

Thanks
Any help for any of the doubts is appreciated

PS: i am trying to implement the system using PHP + Mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
/user/id?access_token=42342342342423
```

rest apis don't need no SEO, so drop the firstname_of_user, just use id, simpler, cleaner, less to maintain.

Comment: according to your example- for any subsequent request the client needs to send  
-> id   
-> accesstoken.    
my doubts are - 
1>where does the client store the id ? as a cookie ?
2>what steps are you following for generating access token ?? and what steps are carried out by the server on getting the access token ??

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your requirement and what we are implementing in our project looks same except different platform, ours is .net.

Follow the same process for login resource with username and password. Once you decide on the mechanism you want to sign this token its not mandatory that it is always appended in the url.

1. Instead of sending the token in the URL try it with the authorization header of http protocol. Use `Authorization  = "Authorization" ":" credentials` [Ref](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

This way you can keep your url same but based on the authentication you can serve resources.

1. You can store this token in cookie for subsequent requests.
2. Removing token from url solves your 3rd doubt.

Hope this helps you up to some extent.